# Angularjs Array indexes not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

This is probably going to be a dumb question but I am stuck too long on this piece, and a fresh pair of eyes could maybe see the issue.

I have two arrays one that holds static data and another that temporarily holds a single index of the main array.

I want to display the temporary array values on a popup and if the new index is chosen the data should cange to the next array value.

> My issue is: If I try to display my fixed array values it gets displayed fine, but
>   if I try to display the temporary array values nothing shows. I am
>   using the exact same technique to display both and only the static
>   array works.

**HTML**

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-model="ModelA" ng-click="$ctrl.Id(1);">More Info</button>

//POPUP
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div ng-controller="PopupCtrl as $ctrl">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h2 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">{{$ctrl.array2}}</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
            <h3>{{$ctrl.array1}}</h3>
            <p>{{$ctrl.array1}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</script>
```

**Javasccript**
**Arrays**

```
    $ctrl.array1 = [{id: 1, name: 'name1'},{id: 2, name: 'name2'}]
    $ctrl.array2 = [];

$ctrl.Id = function (ModelA) {
        console.log('ModelA', ModelA);

        for (var i = 0; i < $ctrl.array1.length; i++) {

            if ($ctrl.array1[i].id == ModelA) {
                $ctrl.array2.push($ctrl.array1[i]);

            }
        }
        $ctrl.open('lg');
    }


    $ctrl.open = function (size) {

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({

                animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
                ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
                ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                controllerAs: '$ctrl',
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    items: function () {
                        return $ctrl.array2;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: are you sure that `array2` is not empty? could you check the value inside the modal

Comment: Yes there is a value in it each time, when I log the value it looks precisely as the static one. @oriaj